# Find a function that represents the quantity of air that is required to inflate it from a radius of $r$ inches until another one of $r+1$ inches.

Tags: geometry

> A spherical globe with radius of $r$ inches has the volume $V(r)=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. Find a function that represents the quantity
>   of air that is required to inflate it from a radius of $r$ inches
>   until another one of $r+1$ inches.

I'm a bit confused with this problem, I think the answer is $V(r+1)-V(r)$ but I'm not sure, could someone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, so you get
$$
V(r+1)-V(r) 
 = \frac{4\pi}{3} \left[(r+1)^3-r^3\right]
 = \frac{4\pi}{3} \left[3r^2+3r+1\right]
 = 4\pi r(r+1) + \frac{4\pi}{3}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct,

The volume is V(r+1)-V(r)

or,

$$\frac{4\pi}{3}\left((r+1)^3-r^3\right)$$